# How to artificially increase CPU usage

Tags: go, cpu

I need a Go code snippet to increase CPU usage, this is to test auto-scaling in a K8s cluster running a pod with my service written in Go. I tried with a loop calculating Sqrt as show below and print the result but it hardly utilizes the CPU.

```
num += math.Sqrt(num)
fmt.Println(num)
```

It would be better if it's not an infinite loop since I need to also stop the load and test scaling in.

Answer (score 21):

You don't really need any "CPU-intensive" calculations; you just have to avoid blocking operations (such as waiting for data on a network connection or writing to a file) and you need at least as many goroutines doing this as CPU cores you have available (this can be queried using [`runtime.NumCPU()`](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#NumCPU)).

Note that you don't even have to manually set the max number of CPUs that can execute simultaneously ([`runtime.GOMAXPROCS()`](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#GOMAXPROCS)), as this defaults to the number of available cores since Go 1.5.

Using [`fmt.Println()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Println) is a bad idea as it may be directed to a file, a network connection etc., and as such, printing to it may block (I/O wait).

Use an "endless" loop which does nothing except check if it's time to abort. You can do this with a single channel, closing it when you want to abort, as receiving on a closed channel can proceed immediately, yielding the zero value of the element type of the channel, and goroutines may check it using the `select` statement while also having a `default` branch, else the `select` statement would just block forever.

Simplest solution:

```
done := make(chan int)

for i := 0; i < runtime.NumCPU(); i++ {
    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case <-done:
                return
            default:
            }
        }
    }()
}

time.Sleep(time.Second * 10)
close(done)
```

Comment: Yep, if trying to stress CPU, avoid blockong operations and just do an endless loop (that can be cancelled).

Comment: Any idea how you would tackle dialing this approach in to hit a particular Target %. Like if you wanted to simulate an 40% or 85% load?

Answer (score 4):

Here's a little snippet that writes `.` characters to `/dev/null` using all your cores, and stops after 10 seconds.

In my case this uses almost 100% of my **Intel Core 2 Duo @ 2.20GHz**, so I don't know how it will behave when executed somewhere with higher specs, but I guess increasing the number of goroutines would do.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "runtime"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    f, err := os.Open(os.DevNull)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer f.Close()

    n := runtime.NumCPU()
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(n)

    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        go func() {
            for {
                fmt.Fprintf(f, ".")
            }
        }()
    }

    time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)
}
```

Comment: This code has race conditions, accesses to the local variable `keepGoing` are not synchronized (run with the `-race` option to verify). Better to use channels for such thing.

Comment: I didn't see the need since this program exits right after the sleep. In fact, now that you mention it, even the `keepGoing` variable is unneeded if this program is to be ran as a whole.

Comment: That is not true. As it is, you're in the hands of the goroutine scheduler, and if the main goroutine does not get scheduled after the sleep, your app might run "forever"..

Comment: Hmm... That is interesting... Today I learned something new. Thanks!

Comment: Check out this code: it should terminate after 1 millisecond, but it runs forever, for the same reason I mentioned above: [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/4Swz4WSG9d). If you think it's playground related, save it locally, and run it. It again will run forever.

Answer (score 2):

noisypixy has the right idea with using all cores, but on my machine it only managed to hit about 50% load on all processors. I believe this is due to Prints being slow, but not CPU intensive.

```
package main

import (
    "runtime"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    n := runtime.NumCPU()
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(n)

    quit := make(chan bool)

    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        go func() {
            for {
                select {
                case <-quit:
                    return
                default:
                }
            }
        }()
    }

    time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        quit <- true
    }
}
```